# past continuous for a short action

Tags: progressive-aspect, past-continuous

> Things had not been the same between Julie and her fiance, David, since he accepted a job in Paris. They had known  each other for almost five years, and in that time, they had never argued much. Lately, though, their relationship 
>   had become stormy.They seemed to be finding fault with each other and disagreeing about everything. For the first time, she **was starting** to wonder if she was ready for marriage.

Why was starting and not started? Is it because of the first times which means  she did it after(but we can't call that a start anymore) . Starting  is a short action that does not go with past continuous.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite common for the progressive construction to be employed in order to "recategorize" a verb which ordinarily has one sort of [aspect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info) into a different aspect.

For instance, stative verbs are not ordinarily cast in the progressive, but may be if the speaker wants us to view the *state* expressed as subject to change over time:

> I'm seeing more and more of him these days.
>   She was now loving him less than she had before.

In the same way, *start* or *finish*, which ordinarily refer only to the moments at which an action is set in motion or completed, may be recategorized as gradual processes.

> He's been finishing his novel for three years now.
>   We're only starting to get a handle on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The **past continuous** is used to describe an action lasting for some time or serving as a background for other events.

We often use the past continuous and the past simple in the same sentence. The past continuous describes a background action or event in the past; the past simple describes a shorter action or event that happened for a longer action, or which interrupted it.

So saying *she was starting* is simple used as a background.